# How to make md5 be supported with ftpasswd

Tags: proftpd

I am using xampp on mac, trying to change the default password in proftpd.conf. I reckon what I need to do is to use ftpasswd get my new password hash and replace the old one in proftpd.conf.

So I did:

```
ftpasswd --hash
```

And typed my new password twice.
But I got warning:

***You requested MD5 passwords but your system does not support it.  Defaulting to DES passwords.***

How can I resolve this to get a md5 hash?

Comment: Why on earth would you use md5 hashing instead of DES?

Comment: @Ramhound As I think proftpd is using md5, isn't it? I think so because I used default password 'xampp' with **ftpasswd --hash**, the result is different than the hash in proftpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

The `ftpasswd` utility that accompanies ProFTPD generates password hashes that are acceptable to the underlying C library's `crypt(3)` function.  So it is not ProFTPD, *per se*, that is using MD5 password hashes (or DES, or anything else); it is ProFTPD using the `crypt(3)` function.

On other Unix/Linux flavors, the `crypt(3)` function can support different hashing algorithms (*e.g.* [DES, MD5, Blowfish, even SHA-256/SHA-512](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html)), identified by the first parts of the generated hash.  Thus a prefix of `"$1$..."` might indicate a DES hashed value, `"$2$...` for MD5, *etc*.  **However**, not every Unix variant supports this syntax; it looks like the MacOSX `crypt(3)` function [does **not**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/crypt.3.html).

The `ftpasswd` calls `crypt(3)`, and examines the returned hash value.  If the `--md5` command-line option was used (thus requesting MD5 hash values), *and* the returned hash value does not begin with `"$2$..."`, then `ftpasswd` indicates that the platform does not support MD5 hashed passwords.  Adding such support involves the C library and perhaps other fundamental libraries; it is thus not an easy task.

Alternatives including using a SQL database for your user database (via the [`mod_sql`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql.html) module); the [`mod_sql_passwd`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sql_passwd.html) module of ProFTPD allows for quite a range of password hashing algorithms/functions.

Also, you probably should **not** be using a default password in your `proftpd.conf`; such things can all too easily leak out.  I'd strongly recommend that you use something like `mod_sql`, or even a separate `AuthUserFile`, or something else.

Hope this helps!

*Full disclaimer: I'm the author of ProFTPD, and the `mod_sql_passwd` module.*